# Frobenius Map and Subfields of $\bar{\mathbb{F}}(x,y)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields

Let $L=\bar{\mathbb{F}}_{p}(x,y)$ (for $\bar{\mathbb{F}_{p}}$ an algebraic closure of the finite field) and let $L^{(p)}$ be the image of $L$ under the Frobenius map $L \rightarrow L $, where $g(x) \mapsto g(x)^{p}$. Show that $[L:L^{(p)}]=p^{2}$ and moreover that there are infinitely many distinct subfields $L^{(p)} \subset E \subset L$.

---

I have shown the first statement (can take as a basis $\{1,x,y,,xy,x^{2},y^{2},\dots,x^{p-1}y^{p-1},x^{p},y^{p}\}$ which will have size $p^{2}$, so the extension is of degree $p^{2}$).

I'm stumped for the second part though. What would be a good observation to get started? (I saw a similar example for $p=2$, not sure on how to generalize this though).

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Try to show the following : a finite field extension is simple (generated by one element) if and only if it has a finite number of subextensions. Then show that your extension cannot be generated by a single element.

Comment: If you want a more explicit suggestion, show that the fields $E_\alpha=L^{(p)}(x+\alpha y)$ are distinct intermediate fields. Here $\alpha$ is ranging over $\overline{\Bbb{F}_p}$.